# Gigabyte 965 S3 Motherboard POST's too fast to enter BIOS

Tags: motherboard, bios

I never had this problem before putting the HDD's on SATA mode in BIOS (actually, I had them put on AHCI), and didn't really need to enter BIOS after that. But now I need to, and the damn POST goes too fast! I know that for Gigabyte S3 motherboards the BIOS key is DEL, so I keep pressing it, press really fast, or any variation of those two actions, but nothing happens. What do?

Comment: That's a strange thing to happen. Are you 100% sure `del` is the right and only key? It may be `esc` or `f12` or even something different. Otherwise the `pause/break` key may be a solution for hanging the POST a while...

Comment: You might be able to find out the correct by looking at the manufacturer's website (or in the manual if there is one).

Comment: I looked it up, and it is `del` for that board (according to the manual).

Answer (score 2):

Couple things you can try:

1) Turn off the system, put your hand flat on the keyboard, effectively holding down a bunch of keys, and turn it on.  You will hopefully get a 'key stuck' POST warning which may help get you into the BIOS.

2) Take out the CMOS battery for a while to reset the BIOS to defaults.  This will often cause the system to stop at the BIOS on next boot so you can set things like the date and such.

Comment: I had to use the #2 battery trick for one mobo.  Previously my success rate in entering BIOS setup was like 1 in 50 tries.  Once in, disable the "quick boot" feature (or never enable it).